# Dragging form error

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an app that has a function of writing microcontroller's eeprom, I send 512 string chars, it writes all good and without any errors, but when I drag a form while sending values through serial, I have a write error. Seems like when I drag form and hold a left mouse pressed on it, all another cmds stop working, and that drag form in the prior as cmd. How to fix it? I tried before send serial:

```
  My.Application.DoEvents()
```

Not much help from it.

```
Private Sub erom_write_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles erom_write.Click
    RichTextBox3.Text = ""
    Label6.Text = "/"
    Label7.Text = (key_erom.Length) / 2
    OK_rs = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = key_erom.Length
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    Call CHeck_CB_Click(sender, e)
    Dim BytesToSend(3) As Byte
    Dim BytesToSend1(1) As Byte
    Dim count As Short
    Dim page As Short

    BytesToSend1(0) = Hex(84)       ' for call write
    BytesToSend1(1) = 0 ' dummy
    SerialPort1.Write(BytesToSend1, 0, BytesToSend1.Length)
    'Threading.Thread.Sleep(700)
    'Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
    page = 0
    For count = 1 To RichTextBox2.Text Step 2  'For count = 249 To Text4.Text * 2 Step 8 page 32
        BytesToSend(0) = (page And &HFF00&) / &H100
        BytesToSend(1) = (page And &HFF&)
        BytesToSend(2) = CLng("&H" & Mid(key_erom, count, 2))
        My.Application.DoEvents()
        If count < RichTextBox2.Text - 1 Then
            BytesToSend(3) = 1
        Else
            BytesToSend(3) = 0
        End If
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        SerialPort1.Write(BytesToSend, 0, BytesToSend.Length)
        My.Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(7)
        If RichTextBox3.Text = "000001020304" Then  'this we get from ic if error write
            Label1.Text = "ERROR"
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
            ProgressBar1.Visible = False
            Label5.Visible = False
            Label7.Visible = False
            check_ckicl = 0
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
        page = page + 1
            Label5.Text = Math.Round(count / 2)
            ProgressBar1.Value = count

    Next
    Label5.Text = ""
    Label7.Text = ""
    Label6.Text = ""
    My.Application.DoEvents()
    ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
```

Update:

```
       Private Sub CHeck_CB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
       CHeck_CB.Click
       If ToolStripComboBox2.Text = "45/52/53" Then
        Call Button2_Click(sender, e)
      End If
      If ToolStripComboBox2.Text = "41/61" Then
        Call boot_61_Click(sender, e)
    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: remove **My.Application.DoEvents()** . If you need this to update values in the UI Controls in real-time, do multithreading with proper Invoke/BeginInvoke methods

Comment: I tried it copuld times, but seems like those methos to hard for me, im recently came from vb6. Also why that drag form interrupt my current methods?? You sya its becouse Doevents?

Comment: Using **Application.DoEvents()** would make it hard to debug the code if an error is happening. In **.NET** related languages you shouldn't be using it, as it only exists there for backward compatibility for VB6. So remove it and debug then check for errors.

Comment: Why dont you write to the eeprom Asynchronously using Threads? That would make sure anything in the UI wont affect its execution!

Comment: I removed all doevents, you was right, i cant drag an form while it doing some another events.So all good, no error. Can you do example of your suggesed methods instead of DoEvents n a solution, if it helps ill accept it

Comment: @RahulKurup examples please, then i will see and understand or at least google it

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039873/vb-net-simple-multithreading?rq=1). Kind of a similar question but with multithreading. You can search for topics on multithreading, invoke, begininvoke, update ui control from another thread

Comment: Do you still need a solution?

Comment: @RahulKurup yes, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using **Multithreading** to update the UI Control while dragging the form.

First of all move everything from *erom_write_Click* to a new method, let's say *UpdateValuesInControl*. So it would be like :

```
Sub UpdateValuesInControl
  RichTextBox3.Text = ""
  Label6.Text = "/"
  Label7.Text = (key_erom.Length) / 2
  OK_rs = 0
  ProgressBar1.Maximum = key_erom.Length
  ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0

  'You don't have to write "Call"
  'Call CHeck_CB_Click(sender, e)

  'You can simply write
   CHeck_CB.BeginInvoke(Sub() 
                    CHeck_CB_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
                    End Sub)

   '
   '
   '
   '
   '
   '
   '
  'And so on, add the rest of the code in this method
  'DO NOT EVER USE "Application.DoEvent"
End Sub
```

Now start a thread when this is clicked, which would call  *UpdateValuesInControl* like:

```
Private Sub erom_write_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles erom_write.Click
     'Below mentioned codes will start a new thread from the main one
     'Thread Class is in System.Threading namespace
     'So write "Imports System.Threading" in the namespace area in your code, which is at the top-most position.
     Dim work As New Thread(AddressOf UpdateValuesInControl) 'This will create a second thread
     work.IsBackground = True
     work.Start()
     'Because UpdateValuesInControl is going to run in a second thread you main thread won't freeze while dragging event is called.
End Sub
```

Now for each control that you have to update a status or show changes in the existing values in the UI, call *Invoke* or *BeginInvoke* to do the same. Here is an example for a single control Invoke method who needs to be updated while dragging is being done.

```
Sub UpdateValuesInControl
'
'
 Label7.BeginInvoke(Sub() 
                      Label7.Text = (key_erom.Length) / 2
                    End Sub)

'
'
'
'
End Sub
```

**NOTE: You would have to Call Invoke or BeginInvoke for every control that needs to be updated**

Also, It would be a good practice if you start naming your UI Controls like:

> lblStatus instead of Label7

This would only help yourself to know the whereabouts of each control

Comment: why in Sub UpdateValuesInControl,  CHeck_CB_Click(sender, e) - sender has red line error " it says something about level of protection

Comment: this click event looke like:     Private Sub CHeck_CB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CHeck_CB.Click

Comment: In **CHeck_CB_Click(sender, e)** do you use this *sender* object and *e* event?? if not, you can simply pass *Nothing*. Check my updated answer for that

Comment: check_cb_click is a button, if i use nothing instead of sender and e, i have error argument doesnt have parameter sender and e on on check_cb_click(sender as object, e As EventArghs)

Comment: Can you post the  *CHeck_CB_Click(sender, e)* click event

Comment: check an update topic, it will easy to see then in a comment section

Comment: Updated, bascily it checks combobox text value then dpends on it - calls 1 of two buttons

Comment: first of all *drop* using *Call*. It's VB6 syntax, not required in VB.NET. And as per your comment, are you using the *sender* object and *e* events in `Button2_Click(sender, e)` and `boot_61_Click(sender, e)`. if NOT again pass Nothing, like `Button2_Click(Nothing, Nothing)` and `boot_61_Click(Nothing, Nothing)`

Comment: ONLY PASS `Nothing` if *sender* and *e* is not required in their individual click events. else you would have to write parameterized thread and methods.

Comment: Thanks, i got it. now i want to test your solution :)

Comment: Kindly Note: As you pass `Nothing` in all those click events,  those methods are now running in a separate thread, So if those click events update any control or their values, Call Invoke/BeginInvoke in them also. If my solution helps do accept it :)

Comment: is it posbbile to use "SerialPort1.Write(BytesToSend, 0, BytesToSend.Length)" with invoke?

Comment: I haven't used `SerialPort` yet, so sorry about that. Check if `SerialPort.Invoke` or `SerialPort.BeginInvoke` exists. If they exist use them accordingly